# C# Combobox Displaying Blank Items

Tags: c#, winforms, combobox

I'm coding a combobox in C# and for some reason the items in the drop down don't have text. When I have selected an item, it is shown in the combo box text field (the drop down list is always blank whenever I click the drop down button). The datasource seems bound properly because the proper values are being returned when I select items, and the size of the drop down list will change depending on how many items the datasource has. Everything looks fine except for the fact that it seems like my drop down is populated with a bunch of empty strings, which it clearly isn't since as soon as an item is selected the proper text will display.

This is the relevant code:

```
if (list.Count > 0)
{
    cboCustomers.DisplayMember = "Name";
    cboCustomers.DataSource = list;                
    cboCustomers.ValueMember = "ID";                
    cboCustomers.SelectedIndex = 0;                
}
```

I have looked for an answer to this but can't find it anywhere...I'm sure it's something really simple, but I can't figure it out. The closest problem I found had an answer suggested to set the display member before the data source, which clearly didn't work.

The list is populated from a database query. This will run on keyUp, the idea is that the list is populated as the person is typing based on the info given. So if I wrote 'S' I'd get a combobox with a dropdown that had all the clients starting with 'S'.

Comment: What is `consignees`?  Show us the declaration for `consignees`, and the code being used to populate it with data.  The `keyUp` thing is suspicious; you'd better show us that code also.  Is this Winforms?

Comment: Could it be as simple as CSS which makes the font the same color as the background.  When selected you would see the text.

Comment: @Hogan: This is most probably not ASP.NET

Comment: Using a made-up array like `var list = new[] { new { Name = "Joe", ID = 1 } }` plus the code in your question, I cannot reproduce your problem. Could you try to provide a minimal example that still reproduces your problem? (e.g. delete all other controls & code, and show us the reduced code of the form).

Comment: this `I'm coding a combobox in C#` means that the combobox is custom drawn by yourself even the `drop-down list`? I don't think this could happen to a standard `ComboBox`

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Given you don't have any anomalies in your binding, you are probably being affected by `DrawMode` property of your ComboBox, which may be set to `OwnerDrawFixed` or `OwnerDrawVariable`. Set it to `Normal` and things should get better.

Comment: It helped and if anyone wants to use OwnerDrawFixed or  OwnerDrawVariable, you will need to implement MeasureItem event handler and Draw item. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.combobox.drawmode(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 2):

> as soon as an item is selected the proper text will display.

A foreground color the same as the background color will produce the same results you are seeing.